# Matrix effect in mathematica?

Tags: plotting, image-processing, animation

this time I write to share my doubt, a friend of mine shared the following video  [Matrix Raining Code Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9k2OCJk81M)  and asked me, is it possible to do this effect in mathematica ?, the first thing that came to mind was to use RANDOMINTEGER [9, {10,10 }] But I do not know how to do the number rain and the color change. Any help to make the effect is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: [Playing with Matrix falling code in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20557/playing-with-matrix-falling-code-in-mathematica)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could be done.

You could use `Graphics[Text[FromLetterNumber[c],{x,y}]]` to place random letters c  at x,y locations. Indeed you could use `RandomInteger[26]` to pick random letter codes for c. The `FromLetterNumber` function can generate different alphabets, including greek, etc. You'd need to decide what range of the xy-plane you'd want to cover with random letters, and how to space them. Use `RandomReal` or `RandomInteger` to pick the starting xy locations. Use `Table` to create a table of random letters distributed over the plane. Use `RGBColor` to set the color. You'll want to print the same set of letters again, with slightly lower brighness above the first printing of the letter. And so on, several times, to create the trail of letters increasing in brightness downward. Create a frame in this manner, then a sequence of frames. Then use `Export` to export the sequence of frames as a movie.

It's a bit of work, but I think you can do it.

Comment: Many thanks Chris for your suggestions, they are working great, the code that I share is my first attempt, I am trying to improve it to obtain a result more like the video that I show, any advice is very useful. Do not mention that I am using mathematica 10.0 and do not have the FromLetterNumber command.     Table[num = 
   Table[Text[
     Style[RandomInteger[{1, 9}], 
      RandomChoice[{Green, White}]], {RandomInteger[{1, 9}], 
      RandomInteger[{1, 9}]}], {200}]; 
  Graphics[{Rectangle[{0, 0}, {10, 10}], num}], {30}];
ListAnimate[%]